# How do I access specific rows in my LINQ model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have a linq query to select 5 random rows from my products table. Once I have the collection in my model how do I access a specific row? I'm using First() to get at my first row but Im not sure what I would use if I wanted to get data from the 3rd row in that query.

Thanks!

```
var Model = (from r in DB.Products select r).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5);

var ProductID1 = Model.First().ProductID;
var ProductID3 = Model.???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only run the query once and then iterate over the rows using foreach or just use the index property to select the appropriate product

```
var Model = (from r in DB.Products select r).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5).ToList();

var ProductID1 = Model[0].ProductID;
var ProductID2 = Model[1].ProductID;
```

Comment: Thats what I was going for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var Model = (from r in DB.Products select r)
             .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
             .Take(5).ToArray(); 

var ProductID1 = Model.First().ProductID;
var ProductID3 = Model.Skip(2).First() <-- 3rd row
```

I added ToArray() to the initial query, based on Douglas' comment.  Otherwise, the query will re-run every time you pull anything out (since linq's .Take(n) is deferred).

Comment: Be careful; since the query is re-evaluated, you might get the same value as `Model.First()`.

Comment: Once you have an array/List you really should access the items by index, not by using `Skip`.  If you're really, really opposed to that, at least use `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate over your result collection, and take the nth index that you want.

```
Product product = null;
int index = 0;

foreach (Product p in DB.Products)
{
    if (index == 3)
    {
        product = p;
        break;
    }

    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you process your query into a List, you can access each element directly by index:

```
var Model = (from r in DB.Products select r)
    .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(5)
    .ToList(); //Process into a list

var ProductID1 = Model[0].ProductID;
var ProductID3 = Model[3].ProductID;
...
var ProductID100 = Model[100].ProductID;
```